# Create object before main is called

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010

I'm currently working on a project and I'm a bit stumped. In C++, in order to make sure some objects were created before `Main ()`, I would create a static instance at the bottom of the .cpp file, say for example:

```
class MyClass {
public:
   MyClass () { someVariable = "HelloWorld"; }
   ~MyClass () {}
   void someFunction () { cout << someVariable << endl; }
private:
   string someVariable;
};

static MyClass myClass;
```

I was wondering is it possible to do the same thing in C#? I've been trying to declare my instances everywhere to get it to work but no luck so far, so any help is very much appreciated!

Comment: Just to clarify - I have a set of objects that when their constructor is called, they are added to a static list of objects - at present the only way I can get this working is by creating them all one by one in the main () method, but I'm trying to avoid that if possible!

Comment: I think you need a [static constructor](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k9x6w0hc(v=vs.80).aspx)

Comment: Are you trying to implement virtual constructor pattern ? You could do it by reflection. Set an custom attribute on the class you want to register. Then, in a static construcor, you look in your assembly(ies) the type with this attribute and create an instance you register.

Comment: Dumb question: Why do you "need" that to occur before main? Couldn't that static list of objects be implemented as a Singleton? That way you could at least implement an interface and use it in the rest of the application through dependency injection and also be able to unit test with ease.

Comment: The object list is actually a singleton - unfortunately I don't know too much about dependancy injection to have a go at that just yet :(

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `Main` method is in a static class (as every method has to be in a class in C#), so you can add a static constructor to that class.

The static constructor is guaranteed in the specification to run before any of the static members in the class is used, so it will run before the static member `Main` is called.

Comment: Or, for simple objects, you can call constructor directly on declaration : static MyObject _Instance = new MyObject()

Comment: For object, can't you just create static field? They should be resolve before any method, static or not is called, right?

Comment: +1. Static constructor for the same class as Main method is the only way to guarantee code execution before Main. All other scenarios are "before first use" which may or may not cause execution to happen before Main.

Comment: @LightStriker: Yes. A static field with an initialiser is basically just a way to have the initialiser in the static constructor without specifically writing the constructor.

Comment: Ah yes, I think I know what your saying - but the way my program works, the constructor calls the static singleton object list and adds itself to it, then the singleton object list has a method called "initialiseObjects" that calls the initialise () method in each object in the list, so would a static constructor be called when the initialise method is called?